# Parsing XML with simplexml_load_string in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
<Stat Type="Venue">Allianz Stadium</Stat>
<Stat Type="City">Torino</Stat>
```

Los nodos anteriores pertenecen a mi archivo XML. lo único que necesito resolver 
es como genero la salida y solo me muestre Allianz Stadium.

mi código es el siguiente

```
foreach ($MatchData->Stat as $stat) {
         echo $stat ."\n"; }
```

al momento de enviar la salida me imprime ambos

Comment: Creo que puedes acceder al primer elemento haciendo algo como esto: `$stat=$MatchData->stat[0]; echo $stat;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres el primer elemento, que se encuentra en el índice `0` del objeto, puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

#### Casteando a `string`

```
$stat = (string) $MatchData->Stat[0];
echo $stat;
```

---

#### Usando el método mágico `__toString()`

```
$stat = $MatchData->Stat[0]->__toString();
echo $stat;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, bro funciona perfeco, solo resolvere un detalle que se imprime dos veces.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.